# How can I delete a function call, leaving its inner content intact?

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

Let's say I have a line like this:

```
a = x(y(z));
```

And I want to change it to:

```
a = y(z);
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: With my [vim-surround-funk](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-surround-funk) plugin, you would do `dsf` (with the cursor on the `x(` or the associated `)`. This plugin also allows you to delete, change and yank a surrounding function call, and paste it around any text object (and there's a text object for function calls, so you can paste it around them too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with your cursor on the `x` type

``` %x``2x ```

- `%` move to the corresponding parenthesis to the one closest to you, i.e. `)`
- `x` delete it
- ``` `` ``` jump back to your previous jump, the starting `x`
- `2x` delete the next two characters, `x(`

If you want this to be more robust you can do a find next and delete instead of the `2x`

```
%x``df(
```

This works when your function name is variable length.

Comment: Thanks! Alternatively `dwx` instead of `df)`

Comment: Huh.. I didn't know I could do ``!

Comment: It is the "last source of a jump" location.

Answer (score 9):

What I use a mapping that leverages Tim Pope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround):

```
nmap <silent> dsf ds)db
```

I use the mapping `dsf` to read as delete surrounding function. Execute this mapping while inside the function call or one of the parens. The mapping is supposed to be the opposite of surround.vim's surround with function mappings, e.g. `Sf`.

Comment: There is also a [PR](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/pull/118) to add `dsf` to surround.vim itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Exchange

Using [exchange.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange), when one of the defined regions to exchange is fully inside the other, the smaller one replaces the larger one.

So, with your cursor on the beginning of the function name, you can use `cx%%cxi(`.

#### Explanation

- The `cx` operator is used in pairs: the first time defines the first region to be exchanged, and the second time defines the second region and performs the exchange. It takes any motion or text object, given after the operator.
- `cx%` defines the first region to exchange as the text from the current cursor position (beginning of function name) to where the `%` motion goes. When not on a bracket, `%` scans forward in the current line until it finds one, then jumps to the matching bracket. After this command, the entire function call will be highlighted.
- `%` moves the cursor to the closing parenthesis of the function call.
- `cxi(` defines the second region to exchange as the inner parenthesized term (so, the function arguments). At this point, the exchange is performed.

### Caveat

If there is any `%`-matchable character before the opening parenthesis for the function call, this pattern falls apart. For example, the following example code would be valid in JavaScript:

```
foo[x](arg);
```

However, the first region would be defined as `foo[x]` and the second one would fail (no matching parenthesized term).

Comment: Didn't quite work. My configuration (and maybe its different than yours) of exchange.vim doesn't move the cursor to the `)` after the first sequence but rather leaves it at the beginning. I had to move two words (the  'x' and '(' ) and then apply. So basically `cx%2w.`

Comment: Oops. To tell the truth, I didn't try this before posting. A more reliable way would be to type `%` again. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Using the `.` method should use `%` as exchange.vim is setup to use the same cut mechanism when triggered this way.

Comment: Ooh, that's clever! Updating the answer again haha

Comment: Wait, that leaves the parentheses intact. Not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Think you need to move two words/characters over (cursor over the `y`).

Comment: That would work for the specific example OP gave, but it's not a general solution to the question asked.